# Access resources from Android library

Tags: android, android-assets

I'm using Android Studio 2.0 and I've created an Android library to keep some classes and a XML data file. The file is placed in the */res* directory but I cannot find any way to access it. I always get a `FileNotFoundException`.

The code I use to open and serialize the file is:

```
try {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.entries = new ArrayList<SomeEntry>();
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();

        InputStream file=assetManager.open("simple.xml");
        someClass= serializer.read(SomeClass.class, file);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm not using the code in an Activity (i it matters).

Comment: assets and `res` are different.

Answer (score 0):

`simple.xml` should be inside `assets` folder.

And make sure that `assetManager` object is equal to `getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("simple.xml");`